# Requisição post indo sem body angular

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic

Estou tendo problema com `ionic 4` e `angular` para fazer uma requisição `post` no caso estou implementando o login, porém não está sendo enviado meu `body` na requisição.

Meus arquivos estão assim:

**BaseRequest.ts**

```
public post(data): Observable<any> {
    let dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

    return this.http.request('POST', this.url, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        body: dataString,
        observe: 'body',
        responseType: 'json'
    }).catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

**Interceptor.ts**

```
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorsService implements HttpInterceptor {

  loaderToShow: any;
  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController
  ) {
  }


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.showLoader();

    const token = "";

    //Authentication by setting header with token value
    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': token
        }
      });
    }

    if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    }

    request = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
    });


    return next.handle(request).catch((err: any) => {
      if (err.status === 401) {
        console.error('error in http-interceptor', err.status);
      }
      this.hideLoader();
      return next.handle(request);
    });
  }

  async showLoader() {
    this.loaderToShow = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Processing Server Request'
    })
    return await this.loaderToShow.present();
  }

  hideLoader() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.loadingController)
      this.loaderToShow.dismiss();
    }, 1000)
  }

}
```

No google chrome emulando o resultado é:

[image: Imagem referente a requisição para api]

Em minha API recebo da seguinte forma:

```
async function apiLogin(rawreq: Request, rawres: Response) {
            let req = rawreq as NGORequest
            let res = rawres as NGOResponse
            let loginparts = req.body.username.split('@');
            let username = loginparts.length == 2 ? loginparts[0] : loginparts[0];
            let domain = loginparts.length == 2 ? loginparts[1] : 'ngo';
            let password = req.body.password;
            let db = await NGOServiceLocator.getDb(domain)
            let user = await db.collection("users").findOne({ login: username });
}
```

E para receber a requisição faço assim:

```
me.server.use("/api/login", apiLogin)
```

A inicialização do servidor e configuração está assim:

```
    function initExpress() {

        me.server.get("/ping", (req, res) => {
            res.json(1).end();
        });

        me.server.use(upgradeReqAndRes);

        let secmw = createSecurity(me);

        me.server.use(compression({ filter: shouldCompress }))

        function shouldCompress(req: Request, res: Response) {
            if (req.headers['x-no-compression']) {

                return false
            }

            // fallback to standard filter function
            return compression.filter(req, res)
        }

        me.server.use(secmw);

        // me.server.use(express.static('webroot'));
        me.server.use(NGOStaticResolve);


        me.server.use(logAndTimeMW);
        me.server.use(cookieparser());

        me.server.use(bodyparser.json({ limit: '150mb' }));
        me.server.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
            limit: '150mb',
            extended: true
        }));

        me.server.use(NGOUploadMW);

        me.server.use(requestQuery.parseQuery);

        me.httpServer = createServer();

        me.httpServer.on('request', me.server);

        mongoose.set('debug', function (col: any, method: any, query: any, doc: any, opts: any) {
            NGOLog.trace(`${col}.${method}(${JSON.stringify(query)})=>${JSON.stringify(doc)}`)
        });
    }
```

Depois de algum tempo esperando a requisição completar recebi este erro no console.log

```
core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost:6100/api/login","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:6100/api/login: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
at zone-evergreen.js:707
at rejected (tslib.es6.js:71)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:34201)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
at zone-evergreen.js:855
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
```

Qual tem sido meu erro, estou errando em `CORS`, enfim não sei porque nao está enviando o body.

Comment: O "provisional headers shown" indica que a requisição não terminou ou então que receberá algum erro de conexão ou CORs a seguir. PS: coloque o resultado de `let dataString = JSON.stringify(data)` em um `console.log(dataString);`

Comment: O resultado foi este do console.log {"username":"root@gerdau.com.br","password":"toor"}

Comment: O "provisional headers shown" indica que a requisição não terminou ou então que receberá algum erro de conexão ou CORs a seguir. Recebeu algum erro no console?

Comment: Não, a requisição é compeltada, porém acontesce o erro na linha que tem             let loginparts = req.body.username.split('@'); pois ele não consegue encontrar o req.body.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Atualizei minha pergunta, agora teve um retorno de erro da api

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu disse no primeiro comentário, "um erro de CORs", se não configurar o CORs no Express para permitir outro dominio a segurança irá barrar, é simples e tem pronto: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erro de CORs, indica que um dominio diferente não pode acessar outro ou não pode mudar "headers padrões", logo você tem que permitir que o dominio da API concorde com o que o cliente (seu app angular) se comunique, já existe pronto para Express, veja: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html, exemplo:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, bateu batata.